# Which strategy follow to create class?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to learn how classes work. I would like to create different classes with some shared elements and others not, but as far as I know I can create it from three different ways:

- Create a class with all the shared elements and then inherit this class and modify specific methods and attributes in the new class. Something like that:

  ```
   class Enemy(object):  
       """Enemy!"""  
      def __init__(self, damage=30, life=100, enemy="Hero"):  
      #And keep defining the class and its methods and attributes in common with all the enemys

   class Troll(Enemy):  
       """Troll!"""
       def __init__ (self, defense=0):  
       #And define the specific attributes and methods for Trolls.
  ```
- Create a class and ask for a type of class, and change the definition of the object from which input it got. Something like that:

  ```
  class Enemy(object):  
       """Enemy!"""  
       def __init__(self, damage=30, defense=0, life=100, type="Troll" enemy="Hero"):  
           if type=="Troll":  
              #Do that for type "Troll"  
           if type=="Goblin":  
              #Do that for type  "Goblin"  
           #And keep defining the class and its methods and attributes for each accepted type
  ```
- Create two different classes and then do multiple inheritance:

  ```
  class Enemy(object):  
      """Enemy!"""  
      def __init__(self, damage=30, life=100, enemy="Hero"):  
          #And keep defining the class and its methods and attributes in common with all the enemys

  class Trolls(object):  
       """Trolls!"""
       def __init__ (self, defense=1, shield=20):  
           #And define the specific attributes and methods for Trolls.  

  class SuperTroll(Enemy, Trolls):
  ```

I see the first one is the easy one that let me be more flexible to create multiple classes with shared methods and attributes. But the second one seems to me more easy to use(or at least I like it), and I can get out of the `if` conditionals whatever I want. And the third one could be practical for mixing different classes without any shared method or attribute, and if they share it wouldn't mess it (or it would?).

**Which one is better?**
But about writing in one or the other way it seems it is just a matter of strategy about how do you want your code. **Is this correct?**

Comment: the second one is not object oriented. what will you do when you would like to add new enemy type? you want to be able to create a new one without changing the base class

Comment: I'm confused by your third approach. Why have a `Trolls` class and a `Troll` class? What's the difference?

Comment: I was about to recommend against the 3rd, but realized that it makes a useful distinction: `Enemy` is a role, which could be applied to various races. `Troll` is a race, but there might be "friend" trolls and "enemy" trolls. That said, it implies a much richer class system than appears to be necessary, so I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: @Elisha Well, I would add it in the class definition, I think it is easier to read one class definition instead of several. But I see the limitations you point out.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe I didn't pick up a good example I just wanted to point out that it comes from two other class. Now is clearer maybe.

Comment: @chepner Yes, this could be also done if I follow the first approach, but apart from this case I would like to learn to apply for more general cases. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is not a good idea; it will lead to a lot of duplicated code, and you have to edit your `Enemy` class every time you come up with a new type of enemy character.

Picking between the first and third is trickier, and will depend on what you want to achieve ("a matter of strategy", as you have it).

The first, single inheritance from `Enemy` for `Troll` and `Goblin`, is useful because it allows you to define all the code that all `Enemy` characters will have once, and only define the differences in the `Troll` and `Goblin` classes. You could extend this further, and have `Enemy` inherit from a superclass (or metaclass) `Character`, that provides the really basic stuff for both `Enemy` and `Hero` classes (e.g. `name`, `health`, ...).

```
class Enemy(Character)

class Troll(Enemy)
```

The third example may be useful if you want to separate characters and roles, e.g. you could have

```
class FriendlyTroll(Troll, Friend)
```

and

```
class UnfriendlyTroll(Troll, Enemy)
```

if those roles are going to mean different instance attributes (e.g. the `Friend` mix-in might introduce a `share` method). This allows for more complexity in your character definitions, but if you are not going to use the extra functionality it is a lot of complication to get your head around, and may lead to intractable multiple-inheritance problems.

**TL;DR**: Use the first one! If you decide later that you *really need* to separate out roles into mix-in classes, that isn't too complex a task.

Comment: Good point against the second case as they pointed in the comments. And thanks for explaining the which strategy is better to follow on which conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
First one:
```

Proper way to go...You are inheriting from what is collectively "ENEMY". Here you can have common things that "ENEMY" has under the class and have individual classes for all types of enemy and also you can well override some of the methods that makes some kind of "ENEMY" distinct.

```
Second one:
```

Not nice or properly object oriented because what if "trolls" have some property that is not shared by other "enemy". You might say that it can go under "if" statement you have but this makes the code very-less manageable which is why you use OOP ( to manage the code, it's not all but one of the reason).

```
Third one:
```

I strongly suggest not using multiple-inheritance as far as possible. Google diamond death problem and you will know why. One rule for multiple-inheritence--"If you think you need multiple inheritance, you are probably wrong. If you know you have to use multiple inheritance, you are probably right."

Comment: There isn't really a diamond problem in python. http://python-history.blogspot.ca/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: I was trying to hint that multiple-inheritance should be the last option.

Comment: Thanks, I will avoid the second one and try to avoid the third then.

Answer (score 1):

Well, classes are what essentially describes differences in *behavior* of the objects of those classes. That is you may choose either approach but only after you sit down and decide:

in *your program* what is the difference between a given troll and an enemy in general. If there's such a difference (i.e. there're situations when "trolls" behave somewhat different from enemies in general, or have their own methods (actions) etc) then you need to differentiate class Troll and class Enemy. If all they differ is their name, then you probably don't need a separate class...

You need multiple inheritance (the 3rd case) only if you need to mix-in behaviors of two unrelated classes. Generally it's a hard way to go, with certain traps and pitfalls. But if you're clever and accurate enough then you may succeed with it.

Comment: At the moment I will avoid the multiple inheritance as I have not yet learned inheritance. Thanks for the help.